# How do I make this code loop 7 times and go to the next row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I've been learning SQL by myself, and I'm stumped on this one.

In this table I'm working on, I have a persons first name and last name as a column, and I'm using a user defined function to concat the two columns to get their full name.

What I have works for one column, but I don't know how to loop it. Here's my code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fullName(
    @firstName VARCHAR(10),
    @lastName VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @fullName VARCHAR(20)
    SELECT @fullName = CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) FROM stray_kids
    RETURN @fullName;   
END
```

Then when I call it with SELECT lastName, firstName,dbo.fullName(firstName, lastName) FROM stray_kids
It comes up with the image I added, which is great for the first row and then I then tried to add a while loop and counters and such but couldn't figure it out. Also, how would I name the new column name?

Thanks if you can help! <3 [my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTNtd.png)

Comment: Sorry, I don' totally understand what you are trying to do, but please try to use loop continue for for loop condition - https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/loops/continue.php

Comment: Maybe this might help,  I have 8 rows of data which consists of a first name and a last name. I'm trying to concat the two together, and with the code I listed above, it does do exactly what I asked.

The problem is, I don't know how to get to the next row in the table to concat the next set of first and last name. There are 8 rows in total on the table.

Comment: I think you're trying to learn SQL. Just to concatenate the names, you don't need to refer the table name inside function. the parameters passing to the function is enough. Remove the table name inside the function as below.
`SELECT @fullName = CONCAT(@firstName, ' ', @lastName) /*FROM stray_kids*/`
This will give you the correct output. You can also use a statement like the below one to get the result.
`SELECT lastName, firstName,CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName) FROM stray_kids`. Hope this will help

Comment: I think you are looking for [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: I appreciate the help, I have no problem with the actual concating the two names, I'm trying to teach myself how to create a function and it is technically doing what I need it to do, I am just not sure how I would get it to do the next person in the list instead of giving me the same full name down the entire list.

Comment: The query in the function returns 1 value , You have not been specific enough you need a where clause passing a value that can be used in the where clause, perhaps the id from the main query.

Comment: For example https://dbfiddle.uk/bBEMUR0h

Comment: One code smell: you are passing two parameters, but ignore them. Instead you select two columns from a row from the table. Now see the comment by KrishnakumarS

Answer (score 2):

The functionality you are after is easily achieved using a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
alter table stray_kids
add FullName as CONCAT(firstName, ' ', lastName);
```

Then you can simply

```
select FullName from stray_kids;
```

Newer versions of SQL Server also support `concat_ws(' ', FirstName, LastName);`

If you *really* wanted to use a function, all you need is

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fullName(
    @firstName VARCHAR(10),
    @lastName VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS VARCHAR(21)
AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN CONCAT(@firstName, ' ', @lastName);   
END
```

Note the return type needs to account for the additional space character... 10 chars seems al ittle short though so perhaps use `varchar(50)`

Comment: Thank you so much! I wanted to make it a function so I could understand how to make a function a bit more. You're the best!